# from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: express, next.js, cors, spotify

I have a next js app where I want to include a section to display my currently-playing track. I have created a separate express app where I complete the authorization process as stated in the spotify documentation, and return my currently playing track as well as the artist and the image successfully when i call my api on the browser.

However, when I try to make a call to it on my next js app I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email%20user-read-currently-playing&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fapi%2Fcallback&state=2db5053330e577d4' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8888/api/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> trial.tsx:31

Note: there is no error when I call the api from the browser (I even have it deployed on vercel and it works). There may be an error with the way I am returning it (?).

I have tried adding cors middleware on the server side as well as on the next js api call but nothing seems to work.

This is my /api/login route called login.js:

```
const login = require('express').Router();
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cors = require('cors');


const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true
}


login.use(cors(corsOptions));


const stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';


login.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const state = generateRandomString(16);
    res.cookie(stateKey, state);

    // your application requests authorization
    const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-currently-playing';
    res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
        querystring.stringify({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: client_id,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        state: state
    }));
});
```

Here is the callback route (/api/callback):

```
const callback = require('express').Router();
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();


callback.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}));

callback.use(bodyparser.json());


const stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

callback.get('/', (req, res) => {


        /* ...callback code to get the authorization token ... */


        //here i return the info once i get it
        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
          
          
          if (body) {
            res.status(200).json({ 
              name: body.item.name, 
              artist: body.item.artists[0].name, 
              album: body.item.album.name, 
              image: body.item.album.images[0].url
            });
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({ name: '', artist: '', album: '', image: ''})
          }

        });
        
  

});
```

Here is how I am making the api call on next js (pages router):

```
const apiCall = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/login', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
      })

      const data = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API CALL: Error fetching currently playing song:', error.message);
    }
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it's working on versel but not working on localhost:3000.

Try adding **"CORS Unblock"** add-on in your browser and test once.

Comment: This did not work :(